# Commiting code after cloning a repository

Tags: git

I cloned PHPMailer to my project and now when I try to stage it for commit using `git add .` I get the following error:

warning: adding embedded git repository: assets/PHPMailer
You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
If you meant to add a submodule, use:
    git submodule add  assets/PHPMailer

If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the index with:

git rm --cached assets/PHPMailer

See "git help submodule" for more information.

What is the cause of this warning? How do I resolve this?

Comment: The cause is `You've added another git repository inside your current repository.` And to resolve it `If you meant to add a submodule, use: git submodule add assets/PHPMailer`.

Comment: You are not supposed to clone repositories inside other repositories. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @tkausl I wouldn't recommend anyone to use submodules unless they really want to and understand what they are doing.

Comment: @curusarn I needed a mailer to send verification emails, campaigns, etc., for my hypothetical website. PHPMailer was a recommended choice. Instead of using composer which I do not know anything about, I cloned the repository into mine.

Comment: You shouldn't be cloning the PHPMailer project. According to the installation page, you should use "Composer" to install it:

PHPMailer is available on Packagist (using semantic versioning), and installation via Composer is the recommended way to install PHPMailer. Just add this line to your composer.json file:
`"phpmailer/phpmailer": "~6.1"`
or run
`composer require phpmailer/phpmailer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a friend of mine for help regarding this. He proposed the following solution:
Simply delete the .git folder of the cloned repository using `sudo rm -rf .git` following which the repository will no longer be recognised as a repository. It will be treated as a folder in the main repository (mine).
It solved the problem. The changes have been staged and committed to github.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cd into your file
$ rm -rf git
Or
$ git checkout -b stable
$ git checkout stable
$ cd ..
$ git submodule update --remote --merge
$ git add .
$ git commit -m”adds submodule to new branch”
$ git push
$ git push --set-upstream origin stable
$ git checkout master
$ git merge stable
$ git add .
$ git commit -m”adds submodules from merged stable branch”
$ git push
```